# Use Record Number in crystal report in c#

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

i am working with windows forms application.i need to put serial no for records which is coming from database,is record number help for me for that solution.i dont have serial no field in database i like add from frontend. I Found that Record no help for me but also some problem in that ,it shows the values with decimal value like 1.00,etc.But i like to show like 1,2 etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking how to change the formatting from

> 1.00

to

> 1

Then you need to:

1. Right-click -> Number
2. Customize -> Number
3. Modify "Decimals" option to be 1 (not 1.0, or 1.00)

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to show serial number from DATABASE? Or is it simply a serial number to be shown on the report? Your question is not clear on this. If you need to show from the database, then you need to know which column to be shown. If it is simply a serial number, use a formula in crystal report.

If your serial numbers are shown as 1.00, 2.00 etc., you need to format the field using the formatter. Right click the field and from the context menu select Format. This will open up the formatter and you can set how the number should be shown on it.

Comment: is it any formula is for calculate serial no

Comment: If you just read the help of crystal report, it has the step-by-step method to add a serial number. Please refer to it.

Comment: I have updated the answer for the edit you have done to the problem.